# How to stop to open keyboard when click on time picker of inline style date picker in iOS 14?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uidatepicker, ios14

I have implement inline style date picker in iOS 14. I want to disable to open keyboard when focus on time picker.

inline style date picker:
[image]

Please help me as soon as possible.

Comment: Did you try to set text field's input view to your date picker?

Comment: @Suhail No, there is no textfield in my screen only single date picker view.

Comment: Then how do you suppose to change the time when the user taps on time picker? User won't have any idea whether to scroll it or swipe it. It won't be user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

If you show both of date and time but don't let the user change it, why you don't only show the date (and then add the custom date as another view).

If you still keep the datePickerMode is dateAndTime, I can only help you disable the time view (the date view can be select normally). You can do something like this (code in Swift)

```
datePicker.subviews[0].subviews[0].subviews[2].isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

But don't forget to check each subviews exit or not.

Below is information of the subview

```
// datePicker.subviews[0] 
datePicker.subviews[0].subviews[0].subviews[2].isUserInteractionEnabled = false

// datePicker.subviews[0].subviews[0]
<_UIDatePickerCalendarContentStackView: 0x7fb9af50c3e0; frame = (2 52; 316 295.667); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000052bfe0>>

// datePicker.subviews[0].subviews[0].subviews
3 elements
  - 0 : <_UIDatePickerCalendarHeaderView: 0x7fb9af50cd70; frame = (0 0; 316 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x6000005483c0>>
  - 1 : <_UIDatePickerCalendarDateView: 0x7fb9b1815370; frame = (0 0; 316 283.667); layer = <CALayer: 0x60000054ea00>>
  - 2 : <_UIDatePickerCalendarTimeView: 0x7fb9b181c800; frame = (0 283.667; 316 12); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000540660>>
```

Comment: Thank for answer, but your solution not work. If i set isUserInteractionEnabled false then i can't change time value.

Comment: @YogendraPatel how you can change the time value without show the keyboard?

Comment: On scrolling or swipe

Comment: @YogendraPatel did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the tap gesture recognizer that is making the keyboard appear. It worked for me. Here is how to do it for a view that contains a property `datePicker: UIDatePicker`

```
override func didMoveToWindow() {
    super.didMoveToWindow()
    guard let stackView = datePicker?.subviews.first?.subviews.first as? UIStackView,
        let bottomCalendarView = stackView.arrangedSubviews.last,
        let timeLabel = bottomCalendarView.subviews.first,
        let tapGesture = timeLabel.gestureRecognizers?.first else { return }
    timeLabel.removeGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
```